# Iphone - managedobjectcontext not properly saving

Tags: iphone, save, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, core-data

Any idea why

```
    //should save the object context.
NSError *error;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"SAVE ERROR");
}
```

when implemented in a view controller(accessed via a drill down tableview) won't properly save the information?  I am passing the moc from the beginning (rootview hands off to tableview, tableview recursively passes it to itself until calls uiview) and any additions I do show up in the table if I pop/push the tableview(unfortunately reloadData in viewWillAppear doesn't want to update it).

Should I be passing the managedObject instead and fetching the context from that?

Comment: what error are you getting? I'd recommend changing your log statement to NSLog(@"error %@, details %@", error [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey]);

Comment: It never throws an error, that is one of the issues as well.  It gives every appearance of working properly, it just isn't playing nice.

Should I have [NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:] in there somewhere?

Comment: it doesnt throw an error, it just returns wheather it was succesful or not...check what the error says kike Elfred suggested

Comment: Error = (NULL).  My point before was since it never throws an error it will never execute that nslog.  

Only could pull that by putting the nslog outside the if statement

Answer (score 2):

Since I was manually creating the sqlite entries in the code on load, I was also manually deleting it in the persistentStoreCoordinator each time the program started.  Unfortunately, I forgot about that aspect.